# Can one style a custom Tweet button AND utilise the data attributes?

Tags: twitter, styles, tweets

I am creating a custom Tweet button with my own styles however it seems when you opt for customising your own you cannot use the data attributes (data-text, data-url etc.). The utilisation of the data attributes only seem available when you use the Twitter styled button that uses the widget javascript (http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js).

Here is some code taken from the Twitter dev website. Below is the Tweet button using the data attributes:

```html
<script src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div>
  <a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button"
    data-url="http://dev.twitter.com/pages/tweet_button"
    data-via="twitterapi"
    data-text="Checking out this page about Tweet Buttons"
    data-related="anywhere:The Javascript API"
    data-count="vertical">Tweet</a>
</div>
```

Now below here is the 'Build your Own' Tweet button:

```html
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
  #custom-tweet-button a {
    display: block;
    padding: 2px 5px 2px 20px;
    background: url('http://a4.twimg.com/images/favicon.gif') left center no-repeat;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
</style>
<div id="custom-tweet-button">
  <a href="http://twitter.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.twitter.com%2Fpages%2Ftweet-button" target="_blank">Tweet</a>
</div>
```

Hopefully that all makes sense...

Comment: Hey @igneosaur please click improve if you're gonna use most of my changes, instead of rejecting it :-)

Comment: @MichaelSørensen Sorry mate, my fault. I was having a look and had an unintentional mouse discharge, clicking the wrong button. Me no work websites good. Couldn't undo so stole the changes off you. I'm an edit stealer.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

For some reason they won't let you use the Javascript data attributes with a custom button so you have to add them to the URL in your HTML. So for your example:

You would then add `&text=your%20text` with your text.

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.twitter.com%2Fpages%2Ftweet-button&text=my%20text%20here" target="_blank">
```

The other codes are the same, just add `&related=` etc.

Make sure you replace any spaces with `%20` and that is it.

Comment: brilliant, but ugly solution. As long as it works! thanks so much.

I suppose I should do some preprocessing and dynamically construct the final string.

Comment: this is somewhat outdated, check here for the documentation, you use query strings but this shows how to do things like add hashtags: https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button/web-intent